# Android Java : Error while running countdown timer

Tags: java, android

I need your help to find an error in my "test" android application.
Until I create the second function "setProgessBar" the app runs without error, but now the error occur everytime. To comment the function call out has no effect.

Here is the code:

```
package my.timer;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Timer1 extends AppCompatActivity {
  private int arrayPosition = 0;
  private long timeValue = 0;
  private boolean indicator = false;
  private double progress;
  private final String[] actions  = {"Phase1" , "Phase2" , "Phase3" , "Phase4"};
  private final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer1);

    final Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionParameter);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            text2.setText(actions[arrayPosition]);
            text1.setText("" + timeValue + "");

            new CountDownTimer(240000, 100) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    timeValue = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 4;
                    text1.setText("" + timeValue + "");

                    if (timeValue == 3 && indicator){
                        if (arrayPosition < 3){
                            arrayPosition++;
                        } else {
                            arrayPosition = 0;
                        }
                        indicator = false;
                        setProgressBar(arrayPosition);

                        text2.setText(actions[arrayPosition]);
                    }

                    if (timeValue == 1){
                        indicator = true;
                    }
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    text1.setText("Geschafft :)");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}

private void setProgressBar(int progressStatus) {

    switch (progressStatus){
        case 0:
            progress = progress + 0.25;
            break;
        case 2:
            progress = progress - 0.25;
            break;
    }

    progressBar.setProgress((int)progress);
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Tim

Comment: What error? That's rather important. The less vague you are, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: Sorry I would tell if I find out how. But I´m new in programming java and find no error code.
But to describe the error, wenn I click the button which start the Countdowmtimer a popup was displayed (Message : "Timer1 was closed")

Comment: The logcat will contain any errors. Knowing how to find out what the errors were is an essential skill in programming.

Comment: There I look already but there are no errors displayed... :(

Comment: Well, then what's even your question? You said "but now the error occur everytime.". Did you just mean the "Timer1 was closed" message? What's the actual problem?

Comment: And if you're new to Java, you should not be doing full UI stuff, or arguably even any android dev. You should be doing small simple programs to learn the language.

Comment: I know it is quit better to start with some basics. The app should be an attempt.

Yes the error is the popup with the message.